# RewriteBase issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

i am working on an mvc cms system. i have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mymvc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i have another in inner folder admin

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mymvc/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the idea is that if i come to this folder i should be able to access my admin files but it keep bringing me to the index of my root folder. The project is working fine on my local system but when i deploy online www.mylcpschoolbook.net/mymvc (my root folder) i find this problem. please what i'm i not getting right?

Answer (score 0):

When you put it online, you need to change the `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

admin folder htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: nop, here is where the file is residing currently [www.mylcpschoolbook.net/mymvc/](http://www.mylcpschoolbook.net/mymvc/) .If you try adding admin it returns to the index page though i have added admin to the RewriteBase in the  admin folder

Comment: i think i got it. i was misusing the case sensitivity by doing my model cal i had to go and do some strtolower() function around some of my codes in the index page. Its working fine now. Thanks!!!